# Java DOM Parser reading xml files information - nodes attributes

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I have got an xml file and try to read in some information and try to arrange them.
The data in the xml looks like:

```
    <Class code="1-10" kind="category">
        <Meta name="P17b-d" value="2"/>
        <SuperClass code="1-10...1-10"/>
        <SubClass code="1-100"/>
        <Rubric kind="preferred">
            <Label xml:lang="de" xml:space="default">Klinische Untersuchung</Label>
        </Rubric>
    </Class>
```

and my Java class looks like:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Importer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
         File inputFile = new File("ops2022.xml");
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
         doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
         NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Class");
         
         for (int temp = 0; temp < 10; temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName() );
            Element iElement = (Element) nNode;
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && iElement.getAttribute("kind").equals("category")   ) {
               Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
               System.out.println("code : " 
                  + eElement.getAttribute("code"));
               System.out.println("Label : " 
                  + eElement
                  .getElementsByTagName("Label")
                  .item(0)
                  .getTextContent());
               System.out.println("SuperClass : " 
                  + eElement
                  .getElementsByTagName("SuperClass")
                  //I don't know how to get the attribute code here
                  );
            } 
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

But how do I get the attribute's information of the "SuperClass" Node? Idon't know why but java handles `eElement.getAttributeNode("SuperClass")` as a node, although it is an Element.  So I can't use the getAttribute().

I added the code in your answer (@Hiran Chaudhuri) to get my needed information:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Importer {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
         File inputFile = new File("ops2022.xml");
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
         doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
         NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Class");
         
         for (int temp = 0; temp < 10; temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName() );
            Element iElement = (Element) nNode;
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && iElement.getAttribute("kind").equals("category")   ) {
               Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
               System.out.println("code : " 
                  + eElement.getAttribute("code"));
               System.out.println("Label : " 
                  + eElement
                  .getElementsByTagName("Label")
                  .item(0)
                  .getTextContent());
               System.out.println("SuperClass : " 
                  + eElement
                  .getElementsByTagName("SuperClass")
                  Node n = eElement.getElementsByTagName("SuperClass").item(0);
               if (n instanceof Attr) {
                   Attr a = (Attr)n;
                   System.out.println(a.getName());
                   System.out.println(a.getValue());
               } 
                  );
            } 
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

And I get the following

```
----------------------------

Current Element :Class

Current Element :Class

Current Element :Class
code : 1-10
Label : Klinische Untersuchung
```

and if I add another else clause like

```
else {
                   Attr a = (Attr)n;
                   System.out.println(a.getValue());
               }
```

java throws the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl cannot be cast to class org.w3c.dom.Attr (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredElementImpl and org.w3c.dom.Attr are in module java.xml of loader 'bootstrap')
    at Importer.main(Importer.java:46)
```

.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code did the job for me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            //for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(i);
                
                //System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName() );
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    String supString = "OPS-2022";
                    NodeList fieldNodes = eElement.getElementsByTagName("SuperClass");
                    for(int j = 0; j < fieldNodes.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node fieldNode = fieldNodes.item(j);
                        NamedNodeMap attributes = fieldNode.getAttributes();
                        Node attr = attributes.getNamedItem("code");
                        if(attr != null) {
                            supString =attr.getTextContent();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With [Element.getAttributeNode()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttributeNode(java.lang.String)) you do receive a subclass/subinterface of Node called Attr. This Attr has [getName()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Attr.html#getName()) and [getValue()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Attr.html#getValue()) methods that you should be interested in.

Using [Element.getAttribute()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)) will directly deliver the value of the corresponding attribute.

If you lost the chance to directly obtain the correct type, you can still recover like

```
Node n = ... // this is the attribute you are interested in
if (n instanceof Attr) {
    Attr a = (Attr)n;
    System.out.println(a.getName());
    System.out.println(a.getValue());
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with your code.

Comment: Oh, it seems I got confused with your working. Your XML document contains all the programming terms. Let me try to provide a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

So you are wondering how to access the SuperClass' code attribute. This code prints exactly the one value:

```
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Class"); // this list only contains Element nodes
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Element nNode = (Element)nList.item(temp); // this is one 'class' element

    NodeList nList2 = nNode.getElementsByTagName("SuperClass"); // this list only contains Element nodes
    for (int temp2 = 0; temp2 < nList2.getLength(); temp2++) {
       Element superclass = (Element)nList2.item(temp2);
       String code = superclass.getAttribute("code");
       System.out.println(code);
    }
}
```

However this code does the same:

```
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String code = xpath.evaluate("/Class/SuperClass/@code", doc);
```

With XPath expressions you can navigate the DOM tree much more efficiently.